# how to hide or show a field after the form is digitally signed | Acrobat pdf forms

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a form that needs to be digitally signed. After the form is signed, all form fields are made readonly from the properties. But my buttons are not hidden.
What can I do to hide the buttons??

PS - I am using acrobat 15

Comment: Downvoter, please suggest any improvements that I can make on my post. I am new acrobat and javascript

Comment: How are you signing? Do you use a signature field?

Comment: @MaxWyss - Yes, I am using a signature field. And I have made all fields readonly using the "Signed" tab in it's Properties. 
What I would like to do is hide the buttons also. The action on triggers are not useful in this context.

Comment: With the signature fields, you have triggers to run JavaScript which do what you want to do, which you show in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no in-built function or property to achieve the desired result. But I got a simple javascript that I could use to make all fields readonly and hide all buttons both at the same time.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
    var fname = this.getNthFieldName(i);
    if(fname.type == "button")
    {
        this.getField(fname).display = display.hidden;
    }
    else if ( fname != "Signature_2" ) 
           this.getField(fname).readonly = true ; 
}
```